# chaining functions with pipe pipe using not the first argument

Tags: python, pandas

In a pipe i want to use the result of previous steps as the second argument to a subsequent step.

In R i can use the result of the previous chain using `.` like so:

`df %>% b(arg1b) %>% c(arg1c, .)`

How to do this in python for example using `pipe`?

```
df.pipe(b, arg1b).pipe(c, arg1c, **)
```

`syntax error`

Comment: A minimum reproducible example would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an active user of `pandas`, but this documentation page on [pandas.DataFrame.pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) seems to cover your case

```
df.pipe(b, arg1b)
  .pipe((c, 'second_arg_name'), arg1c)
```

where `'second_arg_name'` should be replaced with actual name of the second argument in function `c`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a lambda function for full flexibility:

```
(df.pipe(b, arg1b)
   .pipe(lambda x: c(arg1c, x))
)
```